# Averaging Grades: getting 0's instead of user input

Tags: arrays, sorting, while-loop, containers, jtextpane

My code is nearly perfect...i think. I need to take test scores entered by the user (up to a maximum of 50 scores) and then when the user enters -1 it will display all the scores they entered sorted from lowest to highest and then at the bottom of the list it should say "Average is *_*_". Unfortunately when I run it I get a huge list of 0's and I can't figure out where I went wrong. If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class AverageGrades extends JFrame
{
//construct conponents
static JLabel title = new JLabel("Average of Grades");
static JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
static int numberOfGrades = 0;
static int total = 0;
static DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat ("##0.00");

//set array
static int[] grades = new int[50];

//create content pane
public Container createContentPane()
{
    //create JTextPane and center panel
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    northPanel.add(title);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    textPane = addTextToPane();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));
    centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

    //create Container and set attributes
    Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        c.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return c;
}

//method to add new text to JTextPane
public static JTextPane addTextToPane()
{
    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
    try
    {
        // clear previous text
        doc.remove(0,doc.getLength());

        //insert title
        doc.insertString(0,"Grades\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

        //insert grades and calculate average
        for(int j=0; j<grades.length; j++)
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), grades[j] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("large"));
        }
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't insert text");
    }

    return textPane;
}

//method to sort array
public void grades(int grdArray[])
{
    //sort int array
    for (int pass = 1; pass<grdArray.length; pass++)
    {
        for (int element = 0; element<grdArray.length -1; element++)
        {
            swap(grades, element, element + 1);

        }
    }
        addTextToPane();

}


//method to swap elements of array
public void swap(int swapArray[], int first, int second)
{
    int hold;
    hold = swapArray[first];
    swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
    swapArray[second] = hold;
}

//execute method at run time
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    AverageGrades f = new AverageGrades();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    //accept first grade
    int integerInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average"));

    //while loop accepts more grades, keeps count, and calulates the total
    int count = 0;
    int[] grades = new int[50];
    int num = 0;
    while (count<50 && num!= -1)
    {
        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average" + (count+1)));
        if(num!=-1)
            grades[count] = num;
        count++;

    }

    //create content pane
    f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
    f.setSize(600,375);
    f.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected code which solves your issues.

There were two major issues, you were using a local array grades instead of your static global array grades. (So remove the declaration from main)

Secondly, you were never inserting the first value integerInput which caused the first element to be lost.

```
       import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.*;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    class AverageGrades extends JFrame {
        // construct conponents
        static JLabel title = new JLabel("Average of Grades");
        static JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        static int numberOfGrades = 0;
        static int total = 0;
        static DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");

        // set array
        static int[] grades = new int[50];

        // create content pane
        public Container createContentPane() {
            // create JTextPane and center panel
            JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
            northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            northPanel.add(title);

            JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
            textPane = addTextToPane();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            scrollPane
                    .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

            // create Container and set attributes
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
            c.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            c.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            return c;
        }

        // method to add new text to JTextPane
        public static JTextPane addTextToPane() {
            int counter = 0;
            Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
            try {
                // clear previous text
                doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());

                // insert title
                doc.insertString(0, "Grades\n", textPane.getStyle("large"));

//BREAKING IF NUMBER IS 0, SIGNIFIES THAT ALL ELEMENTS ARE COVERED
//counter IS USED TO CALCULATE THE TOTAL NUMBER OF ELEMENTS
                // insert grades and calculate average
                for (int j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) {
                    if (grades[j] != 0) {
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), grades[j] + "\n",
                                textPane.getStyle("large"));
                        counter++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

//THIS LINE INSERTS THE AVERAGE IN THE PANEL
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Average is :"
                        + (total / counter) + "\n", textPane.getStyle("large"));

            } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't insert text");
            }

            return textPane;
        }


//CORRECT THE SORTING FUNCTION
// THE SORTING SHOULD BE IN REVERSE ORDER FOR YOUR REQUIREMENTS

        // method to sort array
        public void grades(int grdArray[]) {
            // sort int array
            for (int pass = 1; pass < grdArray.length; pass++) {
                for (int element = 0; element < grdArray.length - 1; element++) {
                    swap(grades, element, element + 1);

                }
            }
            addTextToPane();

        }


        // method to swap elements of array
        public void swap(int swapArray[], int first, int second) {
            int hold;
            hold = swapArray[first];
            swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
            swapArray[second] = hold;
        }

        // execute method at run time
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            AverageGrades f = new AverageGrades();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // accept first grade
            int integerInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average"));

            // while loop accepts more grades, keeps count, and calulates the total
            int count = 0;
            grades[0] = integerInput;
            count++;
            int num = 0;
            while (count < 50 && num != -1) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average"
                                + (count + 1)));

//USING TOTAL FIELD TO CALCULATE SUM
                if (num != -1) {
                    grades[count] = num;
                    total += grades[count];
                }



                count++;

            }

//CALL THE SORTING FUNCTION AFTER CORRECTING IT

            //f.grades(grades);

            // create content pane
            f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
            f.setSize(600, 375);
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @chettyharish I really appreciate your help now all the scores I enter do appear. However underneath the scores I am still getting a long list of 0's that aren't supposed to be there. Instead, under the last score it is supposed to produce a line that says "Average is ___" and insert the average where the ___ is. And for some reason it is not listing the scores from lowest to highest

Comment: At what location are you calculating the average? I don't see it anywhere. And the long list of zeros, is due to the fact that the array has 50 elements all unused values will be 0

Comment: I have added some comments in the code in CAPS, use them as a guide to correct your mistakes. I have also solved some of them to make it easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `grade` `array` twice: once inside your `class`:

```
static int[] grades = new int[50];
```

then in `main()`:

```
int[] grades = new int[50];
```

Comment: to add to this, you need to give the contentpane your grades array: `f.createContentPane(grades)`

Comment: thank you brokenfoot now it at least shows the test scores I type in but I'm still getting a long list of 0's after the scores and the average still isn't showing. Thank you too Populus. If you could, show me exactly what you mean that'd be awesome I'm still fairly new to Java

Comment: Populus I see what you mean, but after trying to give the pane my grades array it says I cannot because it is an integer

Comment: @Populus just to make sure you saw my comment back

Comment: Regarding the long list of 0s, that's how arrays work, you defined it to the size of 50, so it's length is 50, and the default value in each slot is `0`. If you want to have a variable length array, I suggest you use the `ArrayList` class or some other similar class. Or you can design a class that does that as an exercise if you feel up to the challenge.